# How to retrieve Open XML Relationships?

Tags: openxml-sdk, openxml

I'm using the Open XML SDK 2.0 to open an Excel file.

When I open the .rels file (from the .xlsx/.zip) I can see all the relationships defined.

How can I get a list of these relationships in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpreadsheetDocument.Parts
and
WorkbookPart.Parts

Comment: Could you be more explicit please? How can I get the relationships from WorkbookPart.Parts?

Comment: I think the user try to say that Relationships are a part you can read by iterating through SpreadsheetDocument.Parts or WorkbookPart.Parts. There you would find an element of Relationship you could read

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which relationships you want. As others have mentioned use `.Parts` to fetch relationship information on any `OpenXmlPart`.

You could do it like this:

```
public void GetRelationships(string filepath)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
    {
        // Get relationships at spreadsheet level
        IEnumerable relationships = spreadsheet.Parts;
        foreach (IdPartPair partPair in relationships)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partPair.RelationshipId);
            Console.WriteLine(partPair.OpenXmlPart);
        }

        // Get relationships at workbook level
        IEnumerable relationships2 = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Parts;
        foreach (IdPartPair partPair in relationships2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partPair.RelationshipId);
            Console.WriteLine(partPair.OpenXmlPart);
        }

        // relationships at worksheet level
        IEnumerable worksheetParts = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts;
        foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetPart in worksheetParts)
        {
            IEnumerable relationships3 = worksheetPart.Parts;
            foreach (IdPartPair partPair in relationships3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(partPair.RelationshipId);
                Console.WriteLine(partPair.OpenXmlPart);
            }
        }

        // Perform same concepts on any other OpenXmlPart in the package
    }
}
```